# Omnet++ adding c++ files to corresponding module in .net file

Tags: omnet++, inet

I followed [this tutorial](https://vimeo.com/177198894).

As you can see its a basic multiple client to server communication. I can run it and it works. The clients sends a SYN message to the server and the server answers with an RST + ACK. I even managed to add two more clients to this project. I just have some questions here.

After finishing the tutorial i did not see where we actually said that the clients should start by sending a SYN message etc. How does it really work?

Also as you can see from the tutorial there are several clients  "client1", "client2...etc" How do i connect that "client" to a .cc file? as i want to be able to do stuff like calculate how long it takes for it to send a message and receive and stuff.

Any tips or suggestions or tutorials about this specific subject is helpful thank you!

Comment: I did some assignment using omnet++.Here is link : https://github.com/arpitx165/CN-Lab

Answer (score 0):

Tic-Toc tutorial may help you starting... https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/
In the first page it explains how to define a module.